# How to input arrow keys in autokey

Tags: autokey

I am trying to globally apply a sublime like parenthesis with phrase defined in autokey that when triggered types () and moves mouse cursor left once which is pressing left arrow key in the keyboard.
Currently I am doing...

```
()| -> left arrow once -> (|)
```

What I want...

```
right away (|)
```

Does anybody know how to say autokey to move mouse cursor left?

Answer (score 3):

The final cursor position can be defined using `<cursor>` in your script. Hence, your phrase would become

```
(<cursor>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen this technique before. I'm posting a link to this on the AutoKey list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autokey-users

Comment: This even works in phrases.